# Space between the text is not appearing after saving and publishing the customized developer portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have customized the new developer portal  shown in image below

[image: Portal image before publishing]

But after publishing the space between the text is not appearing

[image: Portal image after publishing]

Moreover, please advise to add image between the paragraphs while customizing .

I tried to add space from the option given while customizing the developer portal

Comment: @Pavan Could you please suggest here why is the space between text not appearing after publishing please.